# How to export Excel data from different sheets to SQL-SERVER Database?

Tags: sql, database, vba, excel

I am new in Excel VBA and SQL. I have managed to create a macro button and push Excel cell data to SQL server tables. However, I am a bit puzzled:

How can I take Excel cell data from different sheets and then push them to different tables in SQL Server database? (Currently, I have 3 sheets - Customers, Test, Information - in one Excel file.)

Current working code:

```vb
Sub Button1_Click()
 
Dim conn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim iRowNo As Integer
Dim sCustomerId, sFirstName, sLastName As String

With Sheets("Customers")
        
    'Open a connection to SQL Server
    conn.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=TESTpc\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=ExcelSQLServerDemo;Trusted_connection=yes"
        
   'Skip the header row
    iRowNo = 2
        
    'Loop until empty cell in CustomerId
    Do Until .Cells(iRowNo, 1) = ""
        sCustomerId = .Cells(iRowNo, 1)
        sFirstName = .Cells(iRowNo, 2)
        sLastName = .Cells(iRowNo, 3)
            
        'Generate and execute sql statement to import the excel rows to SQL Server table
        conn.Execute "INSERT into dbo.Customers (CustomerId, FirstName, LastName) values ('" & sCustomerId & "', '" & sFirstName & "', '" & sLastName & "')"

        iRowNo = iRowNo + 1
    Loop
    
    MsgBox "Customers Exported To Database"
        
    conn.Close
    Set conn = Nothing
    
    End With
End Sub
```

Do I need to store the data in arrays and then push them to the database?

Comment: Change `With Sheets("Customers")` to `With Sheets("Test")` or `With Sheets("Information")`.

Comment: @PaichengWu So do I need to create new Models in the vba? Can't I do it under one Sub? Because I would like to know is there anyway, I can define all 3 sheets under 1 function? For example( "Customers" AND "Infromation" AND "Test") and then push all the data to database after pressing the button - something like this.

Comment: Of course you can put all three in 1 sub.  Without more information about the layout of your three sheets and the schema of your database, I cannot give you more help.  You should learn how sheet `Customers` is inserted, then expand to 2nd, and 3rd sheets.

Comment: Thanks @PaichengWu

Comment: Since you have a sub do the job on sheet `Customers` alone, modify it for sheet `test` and modify for sheet `information`.  Then combine the three subs into one.

Comment: Hi @PaichengWu, I have found another way and that is to select multiple sheets by creating an array. Haven't tested it yet, but will give it a try.
Dim MultipleSheets(2) As String
MultipleSheets(0) = "Customers"
MultipleSheets(1) = "Test"
MultipleSheets(2) = "Information"
Sheets(myarray()).Select

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use insert queries for every row you want to export. Instead, if you want to do it manually, open a recordset:

```vb
Sub Button1_Click()

Dim conn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim iRowNo As Integer
Dim sCustomerId, sFirstName, sLastName As String

With Sheets("Customers")

    'Open a connection to SQL Server
    conn.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=TESTpc\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=ExcelSQLServerDemo;Trusted_connection=yes"
    conn.CursorLocation = adUseClient 'Use a client-side cursor
    rs.Open "SELECT * FROM dbo.Customers", conn, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic 'Open the table into a recordset

   'Skip the header row
    iRowNo = 2

    'Loop until empty cell in CustomerId
    Do Until .Cells(iRowNo, 1) = ""
        rs.AddNew 'Add a new row
        rs!CustomerId = .Cells(iRowNo, 1) 'Set row values
        rs!FirstName = .Cells(iRowNo, 2)
        rs!LastName = .Cells(iRowNo, 3)
        rs.Update 'Commit changes to database, you can try running this once, or once every X rows
        iRowNo = iRowNo + 1
    Loop

    MsgBox "Customers Exported To Database"

    conn.Close
    Set conn = Nothing

    End With
End Sub
```

This has several advantages, including but not limited to increased performance, the ability to insert quoted values and increased stability.

Comment: Hi @Erik von Asmuth, thank you for the explanation. I haven't executed your solution yet. I have a question for my understanding. In ur solution, I can see you are using select statement. My question is, why instead of INSERT, a SELECT statement should be used, because I will be taking the excel data and then transport it to SQL server?
Another question I have 3 more tables with 2 foreign keys. If I want to export the data, then should I just push the data to the first table where the primary key is? Will it also link to the other foreign keys?Will I execute all the functions under one sub?

Comment: Those are a whole lot of questions for a comment. The select statement opens up a recordset, and the other code adds rows to that. Those further questions are not related to this answer thus I won't answer them as a comment here.

Comment: von Asumth thank you for the explanation, now it makes sense. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Use **Sql Server Import and Export Data 64 Bit or 32 Bit**

STEP 1 :[image: screenshot1]

STEP 2: [image: Screenshot2]

STEP 3: [image: Screenshot3]

STEP 4: [image: Screenshot4]

Step 5 :[image: Screenshot5]

Follow the next steps

Comment: Thanks @RoverRoll, but is there any way I can do this using VBA code instead of the straightforward SQL Server Import. Because, I am currently learning